# Menu interferring with save prompt

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am experiencing an issue where if I introduce a user choice menu into my code, a function that produces a save dialog will not appear. If I comment out the menu function then everything works.
A sample of my code is below. I have ripped out a lot of other functions so only the minimum is presented below and will not make any sense but the code does work when commenting out the save_forms def.
I've only been at this for a few weeks so any constructive criticism would be appreciated.

```
import time
import sys
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog as fd

global OU
global tempdir
global fs

def menu():

    print("[1] Number 1")
    print("[2] Number 2")
    print("[0] Exit")

    ou_option = int(input("Enter a number: "))

    if ou_option == 1:
        print("Number 1 selected")
        OU = str("Number1")
    elif ou_option == 2:
        print("Number 2 selected")
        OU = str("Number2")
    elif ou_option == 0:
        print("Exiting")
        time.sleep(1)
        sys.exit()
    else:
        print("Invalid number. Try again...")
        menu()

def save_forms():
    tk2 = Tk()
    tk2.withdraw()

    fs = fd.askdirectory(title='Select output folder')

    if not fs:
        print('User Cancelled')
        time.sleep(1)
        sys.exit()
    else:
        print('Saving...')

menu()
print("Saving Form")
save_forms()
```

Comment: The code you supplied works on my machine, but the file dialog 'modal' appeared *behind* my terminal; I happened to see it because MacOS bounced it in the doc when it opened. Which version of python are you running?

Comment: @BillHorvath I'm using version 3.9.7 and your comment is very helpful. I did not pick up on this and was pulling my hair out as sometimes it would work fine in debug mode.
I'm sure there is a way to make the file dialogs appear up front.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Using `tk1.attributes("-topmost", True)` brings the dialog to the front.
Thanks Bill for the point in the right direction.